# Why my SUBSTRING or LEFT SQL query not displaying

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I trying to limit the number of character in my page so I have this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var connection = require('../connection');

 /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT title, LEFT(bode,12) FROM 
   articles',function(error, results){
    if(error) throw error;

    console.log(results);

    res.render('index',{data: results});
});



});

module.exports = router;
```

and in my view file i have this

```
<% data.forEach(function(data) { %>
    <h1><%= data.title %> </h1>
     <p><%= data.bode %></p>
<% }); %>
```

but nothing is display for the bode part , i get a console log and its showing the correct data but not on my html page , when i take the LEFT our of my query i get the whole bode section but i only want to display 10character

Answer (score 1):

The resultset has 2 columns, one named `"title"`, and one name `"LEFT(bode,12)"`, which isn't easily accessible as a property (nor would you want to).

Try this:

```
SELECT title, LEFT(bode,12) AS bode FROM articles
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i do the same thing with knex

Comment: I have no idea. I see many people having many problems with database abstraction libraries, who are trying to do simple things that are near impossible when using them, that I wonder why they use them at all if they don't know how they work, or even what benefits they offer. The `select {EXPRESSION} [AS alias]` is standard SQL, and if knex doesn't support it, or you can't easily find it in their documentation, I would suggest to not use it.